# In python,i want to make a new array and add elements of another array. I don't know where i'm making mistakes

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, copy

from array import *

arr = array('i',[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])

newArr = array(arr.typecode,(e for e in newArr))

for e in newArr:
print(e)

error:
NameError: name 'newArr' is not defined

Comment: Use `e for e in arr` instead of `e for e in newArr`. You're trying to read from a non existing array here.

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because you are declaring newArr and using it in **array(arr.typecode,(e for e in **newArr**))** in the same line.

What you can do is either declare newArr as an empty array first before that line. For that you can do **newArr=array('i',[])**. Or to achieve your objective as in "add elements to new array"(assuming from the **arr** variable), just replace newArr with arr in **array(arr.typecode,(e for e in newArr))**. That is make it **array(arr.typecode,(e for e in arr))**